# Swiftkey like Text prediction (next word prediction) in Java

Tags: java, text, machine-learning, nlp, prediction

I'm working on an algorithm to predict the next word in a sentence like the SwiftKey app .

I've figured that using the N-Grams model  described here (https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/Engineering/CS-224N/asset/slp4.pdf)
it can be done.

But I would like to know if there are any existing libraries which does the next word prediction ?
(I have looked at OpenNLP and Stanford CoreNLP and figured that they don't have out of the box support for this feature)

Or can you suggest some pointers in building a highly scalable text prediction in java.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: https://github.com/sherjilozair/char-rnn-tensorflow

Comment: How have you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by "highly scalable", one way to model language is with a recurrent neural network. To train such a neural network, you basically pass a sequence of words to the network, and at each word, predict the next word. 
http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/ is a good place to start reading about LSTMs in particular, and https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/recurrent/index.html#lstm is a tutorial which contains working code and explanations of how the code works. It's in python using tensorflow but one reason I point this out is that with this, you could at least see if the accuracy is good enough for your needs. Training would take a while, but the predictions when the model is trained won't be as slow.

In java, http://deeplearning4j.org/recurrentnetwork.html talks about recurrent neural networks and lstms, but there may be some work you'd have to do to get it set up. 
http://deeplearning4j.org/word2vec.html#just might also be of interest. These aren't as "out of the box" as just importing a library, though, so they may not be exactly what you're looking for.